# How do I link models together using foreign key with Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to update three models in django with a task function and link them together using a foreign key. **Event**, **Market** & **Runner**

I would like to be able to query the data in my views and display the data.

A single event has multiple markets and in each market there's multiple runners.

I'm getting an error when I try to use foreign keys to link the three models together.

`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "apimb_event" does not exist`

`STATEMENT:  SELECT "apimb_event"."event_id", "apimb_event"."event_name", "apimb_event"."start_time", "apimb_event"."status" FROM "apimb_event" ORDER BY "apimb_event"."event_id" DESC LIMIT 21`

**Update:** 
After nuking the db and starting over I have a similar error.

```
apimb.models.DoesNotExist: Market matching query does not exist.

psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation: null value in column "event_id" 
violates not-null constraint DETAIL:  Failing row contains 
(1271204194200017, null, null, null, null).
```

I don't think I'm using foreign key's correctly. Each model has a id as a primary key.
I can update and create this data fine without using foreign keys but,
How can I update the model and then query the data to show as below?

```
Event         Market         Runner
event_name_1  market_name_1  runner_name_1
                             runner_name_2
                             runner_name_3
event_name_1  market_name_2  runner_name_1
                             runner_name_2
                             runner_name_3
                             runner_name_4
```

**task_function**

```
@shared_task(bind=True)
def get_events(self):

    api = get_client()
    events = api.market_data.get_events(sport_ids=[9],states=MarketStates.All,
                                                        per_page=200, offset=0,
                                                        include_event_participants=Boolean.T,
                                                        category_ids=None, price_depth=3,
                                                        side=Side.All, session=None)

    for event in events:
        event_name = event["name"]
        event_id = event['id']
        start_time = event['start']
        status = event["status"]

        ev, created = Event.objects.update_or_create(event_id=event_id)

        ev.event_name = event_name
        ev.start_time = start_time
        ev.status = status
        ev.save()

        markets = event["markets"]
        for market in markets:
            event_id = market['event-id']
            market_id = market['id']
            market_name = market['name']
            status = market['status']
            volume = market['volume']    

            ma, created = Market.objects.update_or_create(market_id=market_id) 
            ma.market_name = market_name
            ma.status = status
            ma.volume = volume       
            ma.save()

            runners = market["runners"]
            for runner in runners:
                runner_name = runner['name']
                runner_id = runner['id']
                event_id = runner['event-id']

                runner, created = Runner.objects.update_or_create(runner_id=runner_id)
                runner.event_id = event_id
                runner.runner_name = runner_name
                runner.save()
```

**models.py**

```
class Event(models.Model):
    event_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    status = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=13)

class Market(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    market_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    market_name = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=35)
    status = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=10)
    volume = models.FloatField(null=True, max_length=15)

class Runner(models.Model):
    market = models.ForeignKey(Market, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    runner_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    event_id = models.BigIntegerField(null=True)
    runner_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: Your problem is not foreign keys. The error is telling you about missing tables. Have you run the migrations?

Comment: I have run migrations yes. I nuked the db and started over, ran migrate couple times too.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I realised that I had deleted the migrations folder with the __innit__ file so the new migrations was not taking effect. I do have a similar error however.(updated in question). Do you know why I can't update these models based on my error? Thanks